# Json decode returns null value

Tags: php, json

i know this question ask many time before but still i could't get this working. 
i have a json and when i dump `$TenentsAccessible` output is this

```
string(71) "[{`TenantID`:`test.com`,`Name`:`12thdoor`}]"
```

i need to get the value inside `TenantID` property. so i use json decode to convert this to php array but is returns `null`

```
$jnTenant = json_decode($TenentsAccessible,TRUE);           
$tenantID = $jnTenant["TenantID"];
var_dump($jnTenant); // this return null
```

i try to remove the `&quot` and unwanted characters using this

```
$TenentsAccessible = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $TenentsAccessible);
$TenentsAccessible=preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$TenentsAccessible);
```

i know this type of question ask before but i still could't get this to work. appropriate the hlep. thanks

Comment: That's invalid JSON. JSON uses `"` around property names and strings, not backticks (`\``). The valid version of that would be `[{"TenantID":"test.com","Name":"12thdoor"}]`

Comment: did you encode it using json_encode ?

Comment: Take a loot at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php this wil show you the error, also as @T.J.Crowder says, the json is not correct.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yeah thats the problem when i replace that using double quarts it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check your json code on [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

I tried your code and it's not correct because of backticks (`).

So you should replace with (") to have

```
[{
    "TenantID": "test.com",
    "Name": "12thdoor"
}]
```

As hasan described in his answer, json_decode returns a multi-dimensional array, so to get TenantID:

```
$jnTenant = json_decode('[{"TenantID":"test.com","Name":"12thdoor"}]',true);           
$tenantID = $jnTenant[0]['TenantID'];
var_dump($tenantID) ;
```

If you want to get the "TenantID" in the way you described, you have to modify (if you can) the json like this

```
{
    "TenantID": "test.com",
    "Name": "12thdoor"
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try it :

```
$jnTenant = json_decode('[{"TenantID":"test.com","Name":"12thdoor"}]',true);           
$tenantID = $jnTenant[0]['TenantID'];
var_dump($tenantID) ;
```

correct json and **corect get json** !

for understand this plz `print_r( $jnTenant );`

this varibale is Two-dimensional array .